# Sending an email within login code behind delays site

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I am using the code below to send an email when a user fails logging in to my asp.net website. The email sends fine, but I've noticed that after adding the email functionality that the site is slow to respond with the error messages that are displayed to the user (varied by about 3 - 7 seconds).

Is there a way to have these functions run asynchronously so that there is no delay?

```
Protected Sub LoginUser_LoginError(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles LoginUser.LoginError

    LoginUser.FailureText = "Invalid Username or Password - Please Try Again"

    Dim CurrentUser As MembershipUser = Membership.GetUser(LoginUser.UserName)

    If (CurrentUser IsNot Nothing) Then

        If (CurrentUser.IsLockedOut = True) Then
            LoginUser.FailureText = "Your account has been locked - Contact the system administrator"
        ElseIf (CurrentUser.IsApproved = False) Then
            LoginUser.FailureText = "Your account is disabled - Contact the system administrator"
        End If

        Dim mailobject As New System.Net.Mail.MailMessage()
        Dim myCred As New System.Net.NetworkCredential("info@domain.com", "password")

        mailobject.To.Add("myemail@domain.com")
        mailobject.Subject = CurrentUser.ToString() & " Failed Login"

        mailobject.From = New System.Net.Mail.MailAddress("from@domain.com")
        mailobject.IsBodyHtml = True
        mailobject.Body = "Event message: Membership credential verification failed."

        Dim SmtpMail As New System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient("smtp.domain.com")
        SmtpMail.UseDefaultCredentials = False
        SmtpMail.EnableSsl = False
        SmtpMail.Credentials = myCred
        SmtpMail.Port = 557
        SmtpMail.Send(mailobject)

    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Have you tried using threads?

Comment: Not yet, but would using SendAsync work for this? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x5x13z6h.aspx

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Probably the easiest way would be to start up a new thread and send the message from there. This would be a fire-and-forget.

If I remember my VB.NET lambda syntax, I believe this will look something like:

```
Dim thread As New Thread(
    Sub() 
        ' Do the email stuff here
    End Sub
)
thread.Start()
```

`Thread` is in the `System.Threading` namespace, so you'll need:

```
Imports System.Threading
```